# VS 2017 Git Local Commit DB.lock error on every commit

Tags: git, visual-studio

We are getting this error on every local commit:

> Git failed with a fatal error.error:
>   open(".vs/XXXXXX.Dev.Library/v15/Server/sqlite3/db.lock"): Permission
>   deniedfatal: Unable to process path
>   .vs/XXXXXX.Dev.Library/v15/Server/sqlite3/db.lock

This is a brand new installation of VS 2017 using the local git repository before it can sync to Azure DevOps GIT.

We can manually delete the lock file and then *sync* fine, but it seriously slows down the development process (having to *close*, *delete*, *open*, *commit* every time).

Does anyone know a better long-term fix for this issue?

Comment: If anyone else runs across this and adding ".vs/" to .gitignore doesn't seem to work, making the file in PowerShell and then editing with Notepad++ left the file with wrong type of character encoding. I needed to open it in VS Code and encode it as plain UTF8 and then it worked just fine

Answer (score 455, accepted):

Just add the .vs folder to the [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file.

Here is the template for Visual Studio from GitHub's collection of .gitignore templates, as an example:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

---

If you have any trouble adding the .gitignore file, just follow these steps:

1. On the Team Explorer's window, go to Settings.

[image: Team Explorer - Settings]

2. Then access Repository Settings.

[image: Repository Settings]

3. Finally, click Add in the Ignore File section.

[image]

Done. ;)
This default file already includes the .vs folder.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is the best answare, I only put "2017" in: 

    # Visual Studio 2015/2017 cache/options directory
    .vs/

Comment: Trouble is, `git clean -fxd` gets it's knickers in a twist then.. I need to quit VS before I can clean.  This has only started since VS2017 and did not happen in 2015

Comment: This worked for me too. A perfect answer to a misleading error message.

Comment: @Matheus, after doing this commit staged worked but Commit All and Push still shows same error. What could be done to get it commit and push?

Comment: Worked for me, though doing git in VS seems a bit magic most of the time. I try to pull a rabbit out of the hat but get a chimpanzee instead.

Comment: Hello, despite this file type is in gitignore file I m getting error, still. pls help.

Comment: I was getting the same issue when running `git stash --all` (probably because this includes untracked files) and `.vs` was already correctly git ignored.  However, it worked fine for me if I closed VS while doing this operation.

Comment: @Matheus, I had already the file .gitignore and in this case, I had to EDIT instead ADD, and  add ".vs/" to my .gitignore file, it will result in ignoring file / files under this path for your repo.

Answer (score 67):

1. .vs folder should not be committed.
2. create a file with name ".gitignore" inside the projects git root directory.
3. Add the following line ".vs/" in ".gitignore" file.
4. Now commit your project.

[image]

Comment: Hello, despite this file type is in gitignore file I m getting error, still. pls help.

Answer (score 35):

**Step 1:**
Add .vs/ to your .gitignore file (as said in other answers).

**Step 2:**
It is important to understand, that step 1 WILL NOT remove files within .vs/ from your current branch index, if they have already been added to it. So clear your active branch by issuing:

```
git rm --cached -r .vs/*
```

**Step 3:**
Best to immediately repeat steps 1 and 2 for all other active branches of your project as well.
Otherwise you will easily face the same problems again when switching to an uncleaned branch.

**Pro tip:**
Instead of step 1 you may want to to use this official .gitingore template for VisualStudio that covers much more than just the .vs path:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore
(But still don't forget steps 2 and 3.)

Comment: .vs has been excluded in my .gitignore (.vs/) file and the issue still persist. What else could be the issue with?

Comment: Was able to resolve by running git rm --cached -r .vs/*. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

[VS 2017 Git Local Commit DB.lock error on every commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460039/vs-2017-git-local-commit-db-lock-error-on-every-commit?rq=1)

This issue must have been caused by a corrupt .ignore file.

If your IDE is Visual Studio please follow these steps to resolve this issue:

1. Delete the .gitignore file from your project folder
2. Go to Team Explorer
3. Go to Home in Team Explorer
4. Go to Settings
5. Under GIT, Click Repository Settings
6. Under - Ignore & Attributes Files - Under Ignore File - Click Add. You should see a notification that the Ignore File has been successfully created
7. Build your solution. It will take a little while and create a new .ignore file once build is successful
8. You should now be able to Commit and Push without any further issue

NB: Bear in mind that your version of visual studio might place these options differently. I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I've resolved by creating the .gitignore file.

I've also found a workaround that simply consists on removing db.lock file from the .vs folder but you have to do it every single time and doing this for long makes this an annoying operation.

The best way to solve this issue is to create the .gitignore file as suggested before, but I think that is good to mention also this workaround, just to general knowledge purpose!

Regards,
Tony Grinton

Answer (score 1):

My automatically generated `.gitignore` file contained `/.vs` instead of `.vs/`. Fixing this typo fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

`dotnet` now includes a command for `gitignore`.

Open `cmd.exe` from your project folder and type:

```
dotnet new gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error before, and found that the problem was because I didn't close visual studio

Comment: Seemed simple enough didn't it? Ha, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Git directly thru Visual Studio but using the Git Desktop client.

I did however get a similar error but solved it by closing Visual Studio before Committing changes to master.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an IDE like visual studio and it is open while you sending commands close IDE and try again

```
git add .
```

and other commands, it will workout

Answer (score 0):

For me steps below helped:

- Close Visual Studio 2019
- Delete .vs folder in the Project
- Reopen the Project, .vs folder is automatically created
- Done

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For me these two files I have deleted by mistake, after undo these two files and get added in my changes, I was able to commit my changes to git.

Answer (score 0):

Had this and my .gitignore was inside my project folder, but the main git folders were at the solution level.  Moving .gitignore out to the solution/git level folders worked.  Still not sure how it got there but...

Answer (score 0):

Besides these great answers,

I also checked username, email in VS2017 > Team Explorer > Settings >

- Global settings
- Repository Settings

Basically verified vs Bitbucket credentials (click the 'clone' link to see your given username/repo), since there could be a mismatch.

That said I believe the more important check (particularly if working on same repo from 2x different machines) is the URL to remote repo.

Answer (score -1):

Try to copy the file in to your directory  manually (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\digisol--1147805695\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.vs\digisol\v15\Server\sqlite3 )

Answer (score -1):

I had done above solutions , finally this works solved my problem :

- Close the visual studio
- Run the git bash in the project folder
- Write :

  git add .

  git commit -m "[your comment]"

  git push

Answer (score -2):

To resolve this issue is simple. First Close, the Visual Studio and open the Windows Explorer, Go to location folder .vs and open folder properties and check the option hidden