# Visual studio push to Github

Tags: visual-studio, github, github-for-windows

I have a project I started working on in visual studio and I want to push it to Github. I am new to Github. So far I have added the Github extension to VS and created a folder to store it on Github. I have signed into my github on VS and it's linked to the correct project.

The issue is when I try to sync the project, I have followed this link:
https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/blob/master/docs/using/publishing-an-existing-project-to-github.md

But I am unable to sync my VS project to my Github. The error message I am getting is:

```
    Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: rejected Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes  before pushing again.
Pushing master
Error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ProjectExample/Main'
Error: hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: rejected Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes  before pushing again.
```

Now I have tried to fetch in VS but it doesn't seem to making a difference, the project on my github is an empty folder with the exception of the README.md

Sorry if this seems basic or not explained well, I am still learning how to use the Github extension with VS but I will do my best to clarify any questions. I am kinda unsure of what to do next or solve this, any comments will be much appreciated, thank you all for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have created a non-empty GitHub repository.

Try again, this time with an *empty* (no README, no LICENCE files...) and the initial push should work just fine.

Alternatively, a pull should merge the remote `master` branch (and its `README` file) to your code, after which you could push.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you and this does make sense, I will get back to you on this :)

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) and I needed to change the settings by adding ignore file. Here is the link of how to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460039/vs-2017-git-local-commit-db-lock-error-on-every-commit/47472811