# Why if you create a project from dotnetCLI doesnt add to source control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, git, visual-studio, version-control

Good day to all, 
I´ll explain the "problem":
Imagine this case:
You open VisualStudio and then from the IDE I choose a template and then create it, when its created then you can without problem add that solution to the source control, there´s no problem like this:

[image]

But if you create the project template from the CLI, like this:

[image]

Then you **cannot** just add that solution to the source control, **just simply does´nt add**.

And due to this, it will display the typical error:

[image]

How I can fix this? I dont really find to much info pointing to this problem.

**Thank you very much as usually.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.gitignore` file and add the *.vs* folder

Follow this similar [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460039/vs-2017-git-local-commit-db-lock-error-on-every-commit?rq=1)